# Cache expires_in not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching

I'm trying to cache data like so:

```
def index
    Rails.cache.fetch("someCache", expires_in: 12.hours) do
      'someContent'
    end
    raise Rails.cache.fetch("someCache").inspect
end
```

and everything is ok (it returns `someContent`) until i remove block which sets the value (it's already set for 12 hours, right?) and refresh the page:

```
def index
    raise Rails.cache.fetch("someCache").inspect
end
```

returns `nil`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The actual command for **Rails 5** is:

```
rails dev:cache
```

This command will toggle activation, so if you run it again it will disable development caching.

You will read or these two confirmations:

> Development mode is now being cached.
>
> Development mode is no longer being cached.

More info [here](https://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/01/25/caching-in-development-environment-in-rails5.html).

Answer (score 1):

Resolved:

In order to enable caching in `development` envirounment, you have to create `tmp/caching-dev.txt` in your application root path.